# binary.Read does not handle struct padding as expected

Tags: struct, go, padding

In a recent Go project I need to read a binary data file generated by Python, but due to padding, `binary.Read` in Go doesn't read it properly. Below is a minimal example of my problem.

The struct I deal with if of the following format

```
type Index struct{
    A int32
    B int32
    C int32
    D int64
}
```

As you can see the size of the struct is 4+4+4+8=20, but Python added an extra 4 bytes for alignment. So the size is actually 24.

Below is the runnable Python code I use to write this struct:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding=utf8

import struct

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = range(1, 13)
    format = 'iiiq' * 3
    content = struct.pack(format, *data)
    with open('index.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

the `iiiq` format means there are three 32 bit integers and one 64 bit integer in the struct, which is the same with the `Index` struct I defined earlier. And running this code will generate a file named `index.bin` of size 72, which equals to 24 * 3.

And below is the Go code I use to read `index.bin`:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/binary"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "io"
        "unsafe"
)

type Index struct {
        A int32
        B int32
        C int32
        D int64
}

func main() {
        indexSize := unsafe.Sizeof(Index{})
        fp, _ := os.Open("index.bin")
        defer fp.Close()
        info, _ := fp.Stat()
        fileSize := info.Size()
        entryCnt := fileSize / int64(indexSize)
        fmt.Printf("entry cnt: %d\n", entryCnt)

        readSlice := make([]Index, entryCnt)
        reader := io.Reader(fp)
        _ = binary.Read(reader, binary.LittleEndian, &readSlice)
        fmt.Printf("After read:\n%#v\n", readSlice)
}
```

And this is the output:

```
entry cnt: 3
After read:
[]main.Index{main.Index{A:1, B:2, C:3, D:17179869184}, main.Index{A:0, B:5, C:6, D:7}, main.Index{A:8, B:0, C:9, D:47244640266}}
```

Obviously the output is messed up when reading from the Python generated file.

So my question is, how can I read the python generated file(with padding) in Go properly?

Comment: This http://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees might be helpful.

Comment: @alex Unless I'm seriously misunderstanding something, the memory layout isn't relevant here, as `binary.Read` just reads the elements of the struct in order.

Comment: Perhaps this http://play.golang.org/p/bCfWmKTP25 will help.

Comment: Python's [`struct` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is made to be compatible with C types, not Go types. Use `standard` aligning for platform-independent packing, as described in the linked documentation.

Comment: @alex That shows how the struct happens to be aligned in memory, but my point is that that isn't relevant to reading with `binary.Read`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question properly. But to sum up my answer: Go struct memory layout is specified by the language spec. So you can make it whatever you want it to be. Padding with extra fields (like described below) sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just pad your Go struct to match:

```
type Index struct {
    A int32
    B int32
    C int32
    _ int32
    D int64
}
```

Which produces:

```
[]main.Index{main.Index{A:1, B:2, C:3, _:0, D:4}, main.Index{A:5, B:6, C:7, _:0, D:8}, main.Index{A:9, B:10, C:11, _:0, D:12}}
```

`binary.Read` knows to skip the `_` field:

> When reading into structs, the field data for fields with blank (_) field names is skipped; i.e., blank field names may be used for padding.

(So the `0` values for `_` are not because the padding in the file was set to zero, but because the struct field was initialized to `0` and never changed, and the padding in the file was skipped rather than read.)

Comment: Could you explain why padding before D? I tried to padding after D before posting this, but the value is not right.

Comment: That's just how Python was padding its output, to be aligned on 64-bit boundaries.  `4 << 32` is `17179869184`, which is why that's what your first `D` came out as without skipping the padding first.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type Index struct {
    A int32
    B int32
    C int32
    D int64
}

func readIndex(r io.Reader) (Index, error) {
    var index Index
    var buf [24]byte
    _, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf[:])
    if err != nil {
        return index, err
    }
    index.A = int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf[0:4]))
    index.B = int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf[4:8]))
    index.C = int32(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf[8:12]))
    index.D = int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buf[16:24]))
    return index, nil
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("index.bin")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    indexes := make([]Index, 0, 1024)
    for {
        index, err := readIndex(r)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            return
        }
        indexes = append(indexes, index)
    }
    fmt.Println(indexes)
}
```

Output:

```
[{1 2 3 4} {5 6 7 8} {9 10 11 12}]
```

Input:

```
00000000  01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  09 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00  0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
```

Comment: I'm curious if there is a reason for `io.ReadAtLeast(r, buf[:], len(buf))` vs `io.ReadFull(r, buf[:])`? The semantics in this context are the same but the later is more readable here.

Comment: @DaveC: `ReadFull` is a special form of `ReadAtLeast`. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

@Barber's solution is workable, but I found adding a padding field not so comfortable. And I found a better way of doing it.

Below is the new golang read code which works perfectly:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "unsafe"
)

type Index struct {
    A int32
    B int32
    C int32
    // Pad int32
    D int64
}

func main() {
    indexSize := unsafe.Sizeof(Index{})
    fp, _ := os.Open("index.bin")
    defer fp.Close()
    info, _ := fp.Stat()
    fileSize := info.Size()
    entryCnt := fileSize / int64(indexSize)

    reader := io.Reader(fp)
    allBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    readSlice := *((*[]Index)(unsafe.Pointer(&allBytes)))
    realLen := len(allBytes) / int(indexSize)
    readSlice = readSlice[:realLen]
    fmt.Printf("After read:\n%#v\n", readSlice)
}
```

Output:

```
After read:
[]main.Index{main.Index{A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4}, main.Index{A:5, B:6, C:7, D:8}, main.Index{A:9, B:10, C:11, D:12}}
```

This solution needs no explicit padding field.

The essence here is that if you let golang convert the whole bytes to a slice of `Index` struct, it seems to be able to handle the padding well.

Comment: As long as you're comfortable using `unsafe`, which is called that for a reason.  There's no guarantee that Go's padding will be consistent across machines or versions.  You are here relying on the fact that (on your machine and Go version) Go is padding its struct just like the file.