# Go: Padding struct members to read aligned structs from a binary

Tags: go, struct, padding, memory-alignment

I know that when a Go program reads unpacked structs from a binary file that was written by a C program (or any other program that uses standard alignment), using `binary.Read`, I need to add some padding before certain fields to make sure the struct is read correctly with all the members aligned. [For instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656844/binary-read-does-not-handle-struct-padding-as-expected), in the following example:

```
type Example struct {
    A int32
    B int32
    C int32
    D int64
}
```

I need to add padding before the `D` member to make sure it's aligned:

```golang
type Example struct {
    A int32
    B int32
    C int32
    _ int32
    D int64
}
```

The example above is pretty simple, but sometimes I need to read much more complicated structs, with many members (some of those members might be structs themselves).

Currently I need to make the calculation myself for my Go structs to figure where I should add the padding according to the alignment, which is a long and complicated process.

Is there some tool that can read my code and tell me where I should add padding? Or maybe some Go library function that can get my struct as a parameter and tell me where I should add padding to make sure it's properly aligned?

I've tried tools such as [fieldalignment](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/fieldalignment) and [aligncheck](https://gitlab.com/opennota/check), but they only help with memory optimization of structs, not padding structs without changing the order of the members.